# USB Modem rebooting problem

Tags: python, usb

I have a python program that sends text message using a USB modem, it works fine..
But sometimes when I reboot my device the program cant find the device, so I need unplug than plug back again to work... is there someway for me to locate the usb inside the code without unpluging the device?

At this point:

```
dongle = serial.Serial(port="/dev/serial/by-id/usb-HUAWEI_HUAWEI_Mobile-if02-port0",baudrate=9600,timeout=0,rtscts=0,xonxoff=0)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lsms.py", line 5, in <module>
    dongle = serial.Serial(port="/dev/serial/by-id/usb-HUAWEI_HUAWEI_Mobile-if02-port0",baudrate=9600,timeout=0,rtscts=0,xonxoff=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 260, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 276, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/serial/by-id/usb-HUAWEI_HUAWEI_Mobile-if02-port0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/serial/by-id/usb-HUAWEI_HUAWEI_Mobile-if02-port0'
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to RPI.SE. Just for clarification by "reboot my device the program cant find the device" you mean reboot the RPi and cannot find the USB device? I am using a USB-serial converter on the Pi and it failed just once to be recognized by the usb core (never found the cause). Could you check your logs during boot-up (`journalctl` if on Arch) for anything suspicious with respect to "usb" and "usbcore"? On a side note, now that the error is known it would be could practise to catch the exception in your script (although it wouldn't resolve the error).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.. My USB modem works fine, but everytime I reboot the RPi it doesn't work anymore, I have to unplug than plug back again to work...

Comment: So I'd like to recommend to check the syslog from start up and then again after re-plugging the modem. Does the modem have any indicators whether it is powered or not (like a LED or what)? There is the remote possibility that the power supply of the Pi is insufficient. Could this be ruled out?

Comment: It has a LED and it blinks normal.. when I plug in I can keep using for days, but reboot and no more, need to unplug

Comment: Any news on the logfiles? What is your operation system anyways?

Comment: Please also look into the outputs of `dmesg` and `lsusb` and post some details if possible.

Comment: I got some updates, when the modem is working after lsusb I get: `Bus 001 Device 006: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard` and when its not working `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 12d1:14fe Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.`

Comment: Using this string "12d1:14fe Huawei Technologies Co." for a quick search, it seems that your modem comes up as an mass storage device (usually implemented to provide device drivers). There is a tool `usb_modeswitch' to switch it to modem mode. While not being specific for your modem see: http://bytefish.de/blog/huawei_e352s5/ or https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=175443 (What's you linux distribution by the way?)

Comment: Ghanima, thanks to you I found my answer.... that was hard [link](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-276076.html) and im using orginal raspberry distribution Debian Wheezy

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of `dmesg` and `lsusb` after booting the RPi (with the USB modem not being recognized) as well es after un-/replugging the modem.

Also check out the following Q&A's on the reset and forced re-enumeration of USB devices https://superuser.com/questions/141908/how-do-i-reset-an-usb-device-without-unplugging-it-in-linux and https://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution:

First install usb-modeswitch

```
sudo apt-get install usb-modeswitch
```

Connect the 3g dongle to usb port
then give the command `lsusb` in terminal, it will give something like

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0111 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

here we can see 12d1 as vendor id and 1506 as device id

After that you need to add a configuration to /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf:

Type `sudo nano /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf`

```
DefaultVendor = 0x12d1
DefaultProduct = 0x1506
MessageEndPoint = "0x01"
MessageContent = "55534243000000000000000000000011060000000000000000000000000000"
```

and save. Create a custom udev rule to override the devices initial attempts to be removable storage.

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/10-Huawei-Datacard.rules
```

Paste the following:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idProduct}=="1506", SYSFS{idVendor}=="12d1",
RUN+="/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch --vendor 0x12d1 --product 0x1506 --type option-zerocd"
```

save and reboot

It worked for me, hope it can help.. I use a Huawei E303C usb 3G modem